# Issue connecting a nodejs express API route to a dropdown selector in React.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, get

I want to call the information from the database, in this case a list of 10 adjectives, and populate them into a dropdown select menu.

I attempted this with the code shown in the code below.

What am I doing wrong with my API route and/or GET code in React.js that the dropdown select is not populating with the 10 words in the database?

Backend:

```
//Adjectives Route
app.get("/api/adjectives", (req, res) => {
    // 1. fetch a connection from pool
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // 2. run the query / command
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM runninghilltest.adjectives", 
            (error, results, fields) => {
            // 3. release the connection
            conn.release();
            
            if (error) throw error;

            // 4. return the results in response
            // res.send() writes the content to
            // the RESPONSE stream
            res.send(results);
        });
    });
});
```

Frontend:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AdjectivesDropdown from "./Components/AdjectivesDropdown";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have edited my question and removed all the images, replacing them with just the relevant code. I hope this is better.

Comment: You should be able to narrow it down to the client or the server: is the request wrong, or the response? What if you make the request from another client (postman, curl, ...)? What outputs do you get - errors in the browser or server console?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure about postman/curl, this is my first attempt at this so I would have to do some more research and try one of them out. The error I get is in the terminal and said their is a failure to start the script, but the initial hardcoded message to check if front end is reading from the server does come through, just not the actual data from the database.

Comment: Please re-read [mre] and provide the information we need to understand what's actually happening. If there are logs, _why don't you show them?!_

Answer (score 2):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, I would suggest checking the API first to ensure you can get proper response. One way to do it is to use Postman:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/

After you make sure the API is responding with the data you need, then you can narrow down the problem.

By only looking at the code you provide, the problem I can find is the frontend is not calling the correct API route.

Your API route is:

```
/api/adjectives
```

The route in your frontend code is:

```
/api
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to check out Postman and then keep working at it, and thank you for pointing out the route issue.